# Java Paper Rock Scissors program

Tags: java, methods, parameters, arguments

Paper rock scissors java program.

Ok so the only problem I'm having now is the player's score doesn't update until the second loop around.  Any suggestions?

Thanks again Radiodef for your help!!

Updated code below.......

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class RPS_Game {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char r = 'R';
    char p = 'P';
    char s = 'S';
    char player1 = 0;
    char player2 = 0;
    int player1Score = 0;
    int player2Score = 0;
    int playCount = 0;


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);



    while(playCount < 3) {

        System.out.print("Please enter either (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)iccors: ");
        player1 = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
        System.out.print("Please enter either (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)iccors: ");
        player2 = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

        int winner = winningPlayer(player1, player2);   
        if(winner == 0) {
            System.out.print("\nIt's a tie.  Nobody wins!\n");
            System.out.println("\nPlayer 1: " + (player1Score += 0));
            System.out.println("\nPlayer 2: " + (player2Score += 0));
        }
        if(winner == 1) {
            System.out.print("\nPlayer 1 wins!!\n");
            System.out.println("\nPlayer 1: " + player1Score++);    
            System.out.println("\nPlayer 2: " + (player2Score += 0));
        }
        if(winner == 2) {
            System.out.print("\nPlayer 2 wins!!\n");
            System.out.println("\nPlayer 1: " + (player1Score += 0));
            System.out.println("\nPlayer 2: " + player2Score++);    
        }   
    playCount++;
    }       
}

public static int winningPlayer(int player1,  int player2) {    

    //Player 1 wins 
    int result = 0;
    if(player1 == 'R' && player2 == 'S') {      
        result = 1;
    }
    else if(player1 == 'P' && player2 == 'R') {
        result = 1;
    }   
    else if(player1 == 'S' && player2 == 'P') {
        result = 1;
    }   
    //Player 2 wins 
    else if(player2 == 'R' && player1 == 'S') {
        result = 2;
    }
    else if(player2 == 'P' && player1 == 'R') {
        result = 2;
    }   
    else if(player2 == 'S' && player1 == 'P') {
        result = 2;
    }
    return result;
}   
}
```

Comment: What are you stuck on? What would you like help with? What is the next step you are trying to achieve?

Comment: post your specific question mate.

Comment: @MadProgrammer This question would be just as unclear on CR as it currently is here. By looking through the code once, it looks like the program is unfinished and not completely working as planned, which does not make it a good fit for Code Review.

Comment: Not looking for code review at this point.  Sorry I was unspecific.  So I honestly don't know how to got about the method issues.  I messed up and didn't post the part of the instructions I'm lost on.  Check back in original post in two seconds.

Comment: We actually don't that much care if it's homework or not, we just like questions with a narrow scope and clear premise. (This prompts us for concise answers.)

Comment: I get it, I apologize.  I forgot to add the part I;'m having trouble with.  Basically having issues with how to get the "score" into the main method where I have the while loop.  Not sure where to go from here.  I edited the original code and I'm having issues with that area...

Comment: Why do you declare r p and s chars and never use them? Also, if you were to use them, shouldn't they be final?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems like first you just need to move the call in to the loop:

```
while(playCount < 3) {
    System.out.print("Please enter either (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)iccors: ");
    player1 = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
    System.out.print("Please enter either (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)iccors: ");
    player2 = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

    // recompute the winner each time
    int winner = winningPlayer(player1, player2);
    ...
}
```

For keeping a score, you could just have a variable for each player:

```
int player1Score = 0;
int player2Score = 0;

while (...) {
    ...

    if (winner == 1) {
        ++player1Score;
    }
    if (winner == 2) {
        ++player2Score;
    }
}
```

Or you could do something fancier like use an array:

```
int[] scores = new int[3];

while (...) {
    ...

    ++scores[ winner ];

    for (int i = 1; i < scores.length; ++i) {
        System.out.printf("Player %d score is %d.\n", i, scores[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that helps a lot.  Two question, in the winningPlayer method, for every conditional it is returning 0,1 or 2 depending on which player actually wins.   First, should I leave them as return 1, return 2..., or make it result = 1, result = 2... and return result at the end of the method, I THINK it'd be dong the same thing, if so is there more of a preferred way?  Second, when I add the method call into the while loop is that actually collecting what's being returned i.e. the winner?  Thanks again!

Comment: 1. doesn't matter. It's really a choice of style. If you're a new programmer, try both, but always be consistent about style in the same program. 2. Yes, it's assigning the result value of the method to a new variable. And it will get called again each time the loop repeats with a new result.

Comment: You're awesome Radiodef!!  I got it working correctly.  Except...The only thing is on the first loop if player 1 wins it doesn't actually calculate the score until the second loop around.  I'm gonna update my code in the original post.  Two seconds...

Comment: The simplest thing is to just move your `playerScore++` increments to separate lines (out of the print statements). What you're seeing is: Postfix increment like `i++` increments `i` by 1 but it evaluates to the value before the increment. Prefix increment like `++i` works the other way, where it evaluates to the value after the increment. Take a look at this program: http://ideone.com/1nB2uv `i++` prints the value from before the increment and `++i` prints the value from after the increment.

Comment: I'll play around with it.  Just out of curiosity.  What would be a preferable way to do it...++PlayerScore, playerScore + 1, or adding them on a separate line outside of the print statement?  Also, if I take it out of the print statement wouldn't that not work because it wouldn't actually print the score?

Comment: Use whatever *you* find is the most *understandable*. And I mean move the increment out, but still print the variable. `player2Score++; System.out.println("\nPlayer 2: " + player2Score);` It's more clear and you don't have to worry about subtle evaluation semantics.